# what does catkin_make do during package building

Tags: ros, catkin-make, devel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After creating a package in source folder of catkin workspace , I built the package using catkin_make . I noticed few folders have generated w.r.t the package in devel and build folders of workspace . I couldn't comprehend them . Could someone please tell me what happens for the package after invoking catkin_make ? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253704/what-does-catkin_make-do-during-package-building/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:
So to avoid board members pointing you to documentation again, could you please tell us what you have found yourself, how you understood that and what is still unclear? "a few folders [..] I couldn't comprehend them" is rather vague: which folders specifically, and what was unclear about them?

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-03**:
build has got a folder with the package's name in which there is a CMakefiles folder and a installspace folder which has a .pc file by the package's name.

devel space has got a share folder in which there is a CMake folder with .cmake files   and the install and src folders are untouched .

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-03**:
So what do these folders and files mean and why are they only affecting the build and devel spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is all explained in [wiki/catkin/workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces).

> [..] build has got a folder with the package's name in which there is a CMakefiles folder [..]

From the wiki (emphasis mine):

> 1.2 Build Space
>
> The build space is where CMake is invoked to build the catkin packages in the source space. CMake and catkin **keep their cache information and other intermediate files here**.

So the files you found under `build/$pkg_name` are the files that CMake (and to a certain extend Catkin) generate during what CMake calls the *configure phase* ([random link](http://www.aosabook.org/en/cmake.html) to a page explaining this, I couldn't find something on the CMake site. Refer to *5.2.1 - The CMake Process - The Configure Step*). Examples are things like `CMakeCache.txt` and friends. These are all placed in separate directories, as mixing them wouldn't work.

> [..] and a installspace folder which has a .pc file by the package's name.

From the wiki:

> 1.3 Development (Devel) Space
>
> The development space (or devel space) is **where built targets are placed** prior to being installed. The **way targets are organized in the devel space is the same as their layout when they are installed**.

So the `devel` and the `install` space have their files and directories layed out in similar ways, and they only contain *the results* of the build. For the `devel` space that is limited to things that were generated and compiled (ie: shared libraries and binaries) for the `install` space that includes everything that was included in an `install(..)` statement in the `CMakeLists.txt` (and some additional things like msg headers, but they have `install(..)` targets automagically added).

The `.pc` files you specifically mention are [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) [files](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html). They are generated by the `catkin_package(..)` statement in your `CMakeLists.txt` and include information needed by packages to successfully use and link to other packages.

> [..] devel space has got a share folder in which there is a CMake folder with .cmake files [..]

Those `.cmake` files are CMake [config files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#package-configuration-file). They have a similar function as the `.pc` files and were also generated by `catkin_package(..)`.

> [..] and the install and src folders are untouched .

I'm not sure I understand this last bit.

---

Finally, you might want to read [A Gentle Introduction to Catkin](https://jbohren.com/articles/gentle-catkin-intro#catkin-generates-pkg-config-and-cmake-config-files) by @jbohren. Based on your previous questions I think you'll find it enlightening.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-03**:
Thank you very much ! Brilliant explanation :)